# why is val += someOtherValue so bad?

Tags: c#

why is doing the following so bad?

```
String val = null; 
String someOtherValue = "hello" 

val += someOtherValue;
```

It must be pretty bad, but why is that? I had this line in my program and it slowed everything down immensely!

I'm assuming it's because it keeps re-creating the string? Is this the only reason though?

Comment: How much is "immensely"? How many times did you execute that line (is it in a loop)? Does your program operate differently if you *don't* append `someOtherValue`?

Comment: how did you determine that its the only thing that slowed down your program ?

Comment: to the point that everything just froze! I was parsing out values in an image, so with each pixel in the image (3 bytes large) i was appending a single value i get back. the size of the value i was appending was 1 byte large each time... i changed to using a list, and now it doesn't freeze at all ..

Comment: Solve your problem with *science*, not by *guessing*. Get a profiler, measure the performance of the program, and let the profiler tell you what part is slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That exact code is perfectly fine; the compiler will optimize it away.

Doing that *in a loop* can be slow, since that creates a separate (immutable) `string` object for each concatenation.

Instead, use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: is it better to use StringBuilder or to use a list of strings? and why?

Comment: @BlueMonster: It doesn't matter much.  If you set the capacity correctly (to avoid resizes), StringBuilder should be a bit faster

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the reason is that strings are immutable in C#, which means they can't be changed. The framework is forced to allocate a new string every time you do the +=
Try using StringBuilder instead..

The difference is very noticeable in long loops

Comment: is it better to use StringBuilder or to use a list of strings? and why?

Comment: Note that it is still cheaper to use simple concat (s1 + s2) if you do it less than ~7 times.

Comment: @BlueMonster string.Join("", strs) is better than SB, but not by much. Its fairly simple to make a test for it.

Comment: A list of string is more similar to an array, so it's a different structure. StringBuilder is appropriate for concatenating many strings into one

Comment: @YoryeNathan oh okay, that's pretty neat, i didn't know about that

Comment: @YoryeNathan why do `string.Join("", strs)` when you could just do `string.Concat(strs)`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's a sliver bullet that "this is better than that". It depends on the scenario where you need to concat the strings. Performance vs readability is also an issue here. Sometimes it's better to write a well readable code by compromising a little on the performance.

Referring the [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/10/c-string-compares-and-concatenations.aspx) from James Michael Hare

> The fact is, the concattenation operator (+) has been optimized for
>   speed and looks the **cleanest** for joining together a known set of
>   strings in the simplest manner possible.
>
> StringBuilder, on the other hand, excels when you need to build a
>   string of **inderterminant length**.  Use it in those times when you are
>   looping till you hit a stop condition and building a result and it
>   won’t steer you wrong.
>
> String.Format seems to be the looser from the stats, but consider
>   which of these is more **readable**.  Yes, ignore the fact that you could
>   do this with ToString() on a DateTime.

Have a look on the [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/10/c-string-compares-and-concatenations.aspx), it's worth reading.